# How do I diff the same file between two different commits on the same branch?

Tags: git, git-diff

In Git, how could I compare the same file between two different commits (not contiguous) on the same branch (master for example)?

I'm searching for a ***compare*** feature like the one in [Visual SourceSafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) (VSS) or [Team Foundation Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) (TFS).
Is it possible in Git?

Comment: If you need to do this in GitHub - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838096/820410)

Answer (score 1824, accepted):

From the [`git-diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) manpage:

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
```

For instance, to see the difference for a file "main.c" between now and two commits back, here are three equivalent commands:

```
$ git diff HEAD^^ HEAD main.c
$ git diff HEAD^^..HEAD -- main.c
$ git diff HEAD~2 HEAD -- main.c
```

Comment: The `..` isn't really necessary, though it'll work with it (except in fairly old versions, maybe). You can also use `git log` or `gitk` to find SHA1s to use, should the two commits be very far apart. `gitk` also has a "diff selected -> this" and "diff this -> selected" in its context menu.

Comment: Will this work even if the file name was modified between the 2 commits?

Comment: So what is the purpose of the "--"

Comment: @user64141 The `--` is useful e.g. when you have a file named `-p`. Good to use in scripts, only in rare cases needed in practice.

Comment: Note: you need to use paths relative to the root of the repo. Paths relative to the current working directory will not work.

Comment: `git diff master..HEAD -- $(find your_search_folder/ -name '*.c')` for diffing all `.c` files inside a directory.

Comment: The `HEAD^^^` syntax means "compare to 3 repo commits" ago, not 3 "file commits" ago. A way round this is to specify a date e.g. `git diff -w @{2016-01-01} filename` The `-w` means ignore whitespace changes.

Comment: Assuming we're working with a single branch: suppose you've made a commit and then modified `file.c`. How would you compare the current state of the file to the state of the same file in the previous commit? (I ask because the arguments to the command expect `<commit> <commit>` and not `<current changes yet to be committed> <commit>`)

Comment: To @KevinWheeler - I'm actually seeing the opposite in both ubuntu and windows git. The path must be relative to the current directory, not the depot root. Do you still see the same behavior?

Comment: Does not work for me. Always shows me zero changes, but the file has changes.

Comment: If there is a folder structure change between the commits, then you need to use

git diff commit_hash_1:folder/file.ext commit_hash_2:new_folder/file.ext

Comment: The man page linked doesn't mention `HEAD~2` or even `~`. Also, why does `diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1` or `diff HEAD~3 HEAD~2` etc. return nothing??

Comment: Paths are relative: the command `git diff A B c` from folder `/git-clone/a/b` will give same result as `git diff A B a/b/c` from folder `/git-clone`

Comment: Usually you're comparing head to a different branch, so `git diff OTHER_COMMIT filename` is shorter

Answer (score 378):

You can also compare two different files in two different revisions, like this:

`git diff <revision_1>:<file_1> <revision_2>:<file_2>`

Comment: note that it looks like if `<file_1>` and `<file_2>` are in the current directory, not on the top level git managed directory, one has to prepend `./` on Unix: `<revision_1>:./filename_1`

Comment: <revision>: can be ommitted, so you can diff with a file which was not committed yet.

Comment: Note that on Windows one has to use '/' for file paths, not '\'.

Comment: Is there a way to perform this diff such that one of the two files is local? I.e. when your difftool is opened, the file isn't a copy in a temp directory. In the same vein as the difference between `git diff HEAD..HEAD~1` and `git diff HEAD~1`

Comment: Useful if you've renamed or moved a file.

Answer (score 111):

If you have configured the "difftool" you can use

```
git difftool revision_1:file_1 revision_2:file_2
```

Example: Comparing a file from its last commit to its previous commit on the same branch:
Assuming that if you are in your project root folder

```
$git difftool HEAD:src/main/java/com.xyz.test/MyApp.java HEAD^:src/main/java/com.xyz.test/MyApp.java
```

You should have the following entries in your ~/.gitconfig or in project/.git/config file. Install the p4merge.

```
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
    keepBackup = false
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
    keepBackup = false
[difftool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Perforce/p4merge.exe
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
[difftool]
    keepBackup = false
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Perforce/p4merge.exe
    cmd = p4merge.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Note: If you are using Intellij Enterprise or Community Edition - It has a good tool for doing 3 way merge when doing a merging/rebasing

For simple diff you can right click->Git->Compare with revision
[image]

Select the revision you are interested in

[image]

Intellij will show the diff.

[image]

Answer (score 82):

Check `$ git log`, copy the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) ID of the two different commits, and run the `git diff` command with those IDs. for example:

```
$ git diff (sha-id-one) (sha-id-two)
```

Comment: If you want the diff for a specific file, add the path to it at the end of the command.

Comment: Also do a "git pull" to download the full tree info if the two commits are across diffrerent branches. Otherwise you will get a "fatal: bad object" error.

Comment: `git diff (sha-id-one) (sha-id-two) -- filename.ext`  without the filename it will list diffs of *all* files in those two commits.

Answer (score 44):

If you want to see all changes to the file between the two commits on a commit-by-commit basis, you can also do

`git log -u $start_commit..$end_commit -- path/to/file`

Comment: What is "$start_commit" and "$end_commit"? Are they literal, or if not, can you provide an example?

Comment: Those are shell variables that contain the start and end revision, which can instead be sha1 literals or refs

Answer (score 23):

Here is a Perl script that prints out Git diff commands for a given file as found in a Git log command.

E.g.

```
git log pom.xml | perl gldiff.pl 3 pom.xml
```

Yields:

```
git diff 5cc287:pom.xml e8e420:pom.xml
git diff 3aa914:pom.xml 7476e1:pom.xml
git diff 422bfd:pom.xml f92ad8:pom.xml
```

which could then be cut and pasted in a shell window session or piped to `/bin/sh`.

Notes:

1. the number (3 in this case) specifies how many lines to print
2. the file (pom.xml in this case) must agree in both places (you could wrap it in a shell function to provide the same file in both places) or put it in a binary directory as a shell script

Code:

```
# gldiff.pl
use strict;

my $max  = shift;
my $file = shift;

die "not a number" unless $max =~ m/\d+/;
die "not a file"   unless -f $file;

my $count;
my @lines;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    next unless s/^commit\s+(.*)//;
    my $commit = $1;
    push @lines, sprintf "%s:%s", substr($commit,0,6),$file;
    if (@lines == 2) {
        printf "git diff %s %s\n", @lines;
        @lines = ();
    }
    last if ++$count >= $max *2;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you have several files or directories and want to compare non continuous commits, you could do this:

Make a temporary branch (*"revision"* in this example)

```
git checkout -b revision
```

Rewind to the first commit target

```
git reset --hard <commit_target>
```

Cherry picking on those commit interested

```
git cherry-pick <commit_interested> ...
```

Apply diff

```
git diff <commit-target>^
```

When you done

```
git branch -D revision
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  It worked well for my use case.  The only thing i would update is that when your done you can't delete the branch until you switch off of it.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to make a diff with more than one file, with the method specified by @mipadi:

E.g. diff between `HEAD` and your `master`, to find all `.coffee` files:

```
git diff master..HEAD -- `find your_search_folder/ -name '*.coffee'`
```

This will recursively search your `your_search_folder/` for all `.coffee` files and make a diff between them and their `master` versions.

Answer (score 13):

Just another way to use Git's awesomeness...

```
git difftool HEAD HEAD@{N} /PATH/FILE.ext
```

Comment: I defined an alias from this answer that works with bash: ```difftool-file = "!git difftool HEAD@{\"$2\"} HEAD \"$1\" #"```

Answer (score 11):

All the other responses are more complete, so upvote them.
This one is just to remember that you can avoid knowing the id of the recent commit.   Usually, I set my self in the branch that I want to compare and run diff tools knowing the old commit uid (You can use other notations):

```
git checkout master
git difftool 6f8bba my/file/relative/path.py
```

Also, check this other response here to set the tool you want git open to compare the file:
[Configuring diff tool with .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412516/configuring-diff-tool-with-gitconfig)
And to learn more about difftool, [go to the difftool doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)

Comment: Cannot you use HEAD as an alias for the most recent commit ID?  HEAD^ for the one before that, and HEAD^^ for the one before that, etc? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: ^^ don't work. but check this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection
under ancestor selection :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a simple visual comparison on Windows such as you can get in [Visual SourceSafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) or [Team Foundation Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) (TFS), try this:

- right-click on the file in File Explorer
- select 'Git History'

*Note: After upgrading to Windows 10 I have lost the Git context menu options. However, you can achieve the same thing using 'gitk' or 'gitk filename' in a command window.*

Once you call 'Git History', the Git GUI tool will start, with a history of the file in the top left pane. Select one of the versions you would like to compare. Then right-click on the second version and choose either

Diff this -> selected

or

Diff selected -> this

Colour-coded differences will appear in the lower left-hand pane.

Comment: Note to downvoters: this is a simple solution, easy to implement and addresses the OP's issue. It works on Windows which the OP is clearly using (see references to TFS and VSS in the question).