# git diff between branches but ignoring the effect of certain commits

Tags: git

We have 2 branches

- master
- branchX

BranchX was created to solve some compatibility problem, where a about 10 files had to be changed.

Development on master continues and at a certain stage, I want to check what will change when we merge master into branchX.

What command should I use so that I can check that all merges have been done (except for the modifications on these 10 files)

Comment: I'm re-reading your question, and the last sentence doesn't make sense to me: "What command should I use so that I can check that all merges have been done (except for the modifications on these 10 files)"

Have you already merged back in and you're trying to see what *did* change?

Comment: Yes - this might be confusing.   The 10 files will always be different from what we have on master.   I just want to be sure that modifications on all other files are tracked, as if the two branches are in sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ git diff branchX...master
```

Notice that it is **three** dots, which gets the difference between the common ancester of branchX and master, and master itself.

Comment: What an amazing little thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could do by **rewind** to the first commit and **cherry-picking** all those commit that you are interested.
Please, check the code on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122691/1610981)