# How can I copy files from a branch to another using git?

Tags: git

I have a git repository with two branches: `master` and `gh-pages`. If I want to copy a file `foo` from `master` to `gh-pages` without merging them. What command should I use? Many thanks.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can:

```
git checkout gh-pages
git checkout master foo
git commit -m 'Add file foo to gh-pages.'
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but it seems that `foo` file must be commited first. But it works fine. Thank you. If I have enough reputations, I'll vote up you~

Comment: Of course it has to be committed first—otherwise it's not "on that branch", it's just in your working copy.  If that is the case, you should use `git stash`.

Comment: Or, if it is uncommitted, just checkout the desired branch. The uncommitted change will stay with you ready checkin.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare all the diffs between 2 branches: you can use `git difftool master gh-pages` or `git difftool <SHA1 of gh-pages> .`

If you want to get diff for specific list of files follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338126/git-how-to-diff-the-same-file-between-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch):

```
git diff master gh-pages -- path/to/file
```

Comment: It doesn't work fine, it will show all files different between the two branches. It can be very annoying. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score -1):

The Way I would do it: When you commit you have a choice of what to commit and push. So commit only `foo` from `master` then push it, Then just merge that on github/bitbucket whatever to `gh-pages`

Comment: Only commit `foo`? It's a useless commit. That will force others pull it and make them annoyed. It is worse than using `cp` command.

Comment: Errrr~~ I'm sorry I didn't understand you clearly. It seemed you meant    I should merge `master` and `gh-pages`. Is that right?

Answer (score -1):

Also may do cherry-pick from *master* to *gh-pages* after commit **foo**.(After cherry-pick must execute *git add [path to foo]* and commit)