# Git view diff of files in recently merged branch

Tags: git

I'm working with a remote repository on a project. What I did just now was fetch the master branch and merge it with my local master branch. It showed that three files were affected. So far so good.

Now I want to see what the other person changed in one of these files. Let's say that file is `Models/GetUser.php`. I tried `git diff Models/GetUser.php` but of course that won't work as the changes are merged by now.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `git log -- Models/GetUser.php` that will give you all the commit messages for a specific file.

To check actual changes you do this.

`git diff <revision_1>:<file_1> <revision_2>:<file_2>`

or

`git diff <start_commit>.. <end_commit> -- path/to/file`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338126/git-how-to-diff-the-same-file-between-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch) is a link to similar question on SO.

Comment: The problem is that the developer changed several files in that commit, and so didn't provide comments for each file. I want to see exactly what code has changed.

Comment: Check my edit, you should be able to do a `git diff <revision>, and you can get that revision number from `git log`, so the log will show you all the commits made, then the diff will show you all the changes made to a file based on that commit start.