# How can I use Git to check a revision's file list and diff information?

Tags: git, list, file, diff

`git log` only gives me the comment. How can I know the files changed by a Git commit/push, and how each file diffs?

I suppose Git should have a direct command, or a command parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all the files in a commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit)

Comment: For your second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338126/how-to-diff-the-same-file-between-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "git show" to view an object's details and for commits this will by default show all the diffs for the commit.

```
git show e6549b09
```

Both show and log have lots of formatting options and the command line is similar to control the amount of information output. For example, "--stat" will show you a summary of the changes made.

```
git show --stat e6549b09
```

Checkout the help pages,

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log