# Alternative to show changes between commits highlighted

Tags: git

Is there an alternative to show changes in git between commits? Maybe even highlighted in the command line interface to show insertions and deletions?
Now I always have to open the browser and go to github to see the changes highlighted in green and red.

Comment: Would `git diff` do?

Comment: yes, Is this commonly used? What about gitk? is it better?

Comment: btw: Can I do everything just using command line what I can do in the browser except for creating and deleting repos?

Comment: `git diff` is the way one compares commits in git. The other tools, like github or gitk, use it.

Comment: You can also create and delete repos without the browser. `git init` and `rm -r /path/to/my/repo`

Comment: I mean completely neglect the browser and create a remote repository, not a local

Comment: Yep. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diff the same file between two different commits on the same branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338126/how-do-i-diff-the-same-file-between-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch)