# How to compare two commits without providing exact commit hash versions?

Tags: git, git-diff

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3338145/391104

I have tried all the following methods to query the difference between the last two commits **that changed a given file** (not just the most recent two commits, but two specific commits that had a specific effect). Unfortunately, none works for me.

git version 1.8.3.1

```
$ git diff HEAD^^ HEAD main.c
$ git diff HEAD^^..HEAD -- main.c
$ git diff HEAD~2 HEAD -- main.c
```

The only method that worked is to provide two commit hash versions.

**Question**> Do you know why I cannot use HEAD above to compare?

Here is what I have tried:

```
$ git lg1 abc.xml |head -n 3
* 3f13aa1 - (3 hours ago) test 2 - guest
* d59d3bc - (8 months ago) test 1 - guest
* 3a19f36 - (1 year, 2 months ago) test 0 - guest

$ git diff d59d3bc..3f13aa1 abc.xml
diff --git a/abc.xml b/abc.xml
index 5db0595..2790562 100644
--- a/abc.xml
+++ b/abc.xml
@@ -40,6 +40,12 @@
     Hello
+    World

$ git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1 abc.xml
$ git diff HEAD^^ HEAD abc.xml
$ git diff HEAD^^..HEAD abc.xml
$ git diff HEAD~..HEAD abc.xml
```

Comment: When you say "none works" why not? Do you get an error, if so can you please paste the output?

Comment: @CoryKramer, I just updated my OP.

Comment: Note that `d59d3bc..3f13aa1` is `HEAD~..HEAD`. You're trying different revisions. Use `git rev-parse <revision>` to check which commits you're comparing. Use `git log -p` to be sure there's differences in the commits you're comparing.

Comment: @Schwern, I tried "HEAD~..HEAD" and it shows no difference.

Comment: @q0987 And what do `git rev-parse HEAD` and `git rev-parse HEAD~` say? Are they 3f13aa1 and d59d3bc?

Comment: @Schwern, no. I think Mureinik has answered the question for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HEAD` is not the last commit on a file - it's the last commit in the branch that's currently checked out. If the last few commits didn't affect the file in question, using `HEAD` will indeed return an empty output.

If you want to see what the latest commit did to a file, using the `-p` flag of `git log` may be easier:

```
git log -n1 -p abc.xml
```