# How do I to compare two commits of two branches?

Tags: git, git-diff

Hope you're doing well. Thank you for checking out this issue of mine.

I'd like to git diff two commits of two different branches like the following:

```bash
git diff temp-branch/working_directory..main/specific_commit
```

Testing git repo example:

```bash
git init

# first write
echo "this is a line" >> file1.txt
git add file1.txt && git commit -m "write a line to file1"

# second write
echo "this is the second line" >> file1.txt
git add file1.txt && git commit -m "write second line to file1"

# third write
echo "this is the third line" >> file1.txt
git add file1.txt && git commit -m "write third line to file1"

# fourth write
echo "this is the fourth line" >> file1.txt
git add file1.txt && git commit -m "write fourth line to file1"
```

`main`'s `git log`:

```
commit d68dfcb1537154d0d2c0de1ab6f432032a642fd4 (HEAD -> main)

    write fourth line to file1

commit f2538275051c139db38afda1b05d24b3128ef601

    write third line to file1

commit 09d3644bf509b58251123033d565564b0a30bcfa

    write second line to file1

commit 3801f8850f9480a2ac9644ba65705386d9319e61

    write a line to file1
```

Now I'll do the following: creating a branch with a specific commit ("write second line to file1"), such that the `HEAD` is `09d3644bf509b58251123033d565564b0a30bcfa`:

```bash
git checkout -b temp-branch 09d3644bf509b58251123033d565564b0a30bcfa
```

Then I'll write the fifth line to file1.txt:

```bash
echo "this is the fifth line" >> file1.txt
```

`temp-branch`'s `git status`:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   file1.txt
```

`temp-branch`'s `git log`:

```
commit 09d3644bf509b58251123033d565564b0a30bcfa (HEAD -> temp-branch)

    write second line to file1

commit 3801f8850f9480a2ac9644ba65705386d9319e61

    write a line to file1
```

Given the current checkout branch is `temp-branch`. How do I compare `temp-branch` working directory with `main`'s specific commit that's not HEAD (`e.g., f2538275051c139db38afda1b05d24b3128ef601`)? I'd like to compare `temp-branch`'s "this is the fifth line" with `main`'s "this is the third line".

In other words, I'd like to git diff `temp-branch`'s working directory with `main`'s `f2538275051c139db38afda1b05d24b3128ef601`.

Any input is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `git diff commit1 commit2` to compare 2 commits as long as both commits are available in the repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay That's the issue: `temp-branch` HEAD points to an older commit of `main` and so the commit I want to compare are non-existent in `temp-branch`

Comment: Why do you think compared commits somehow have to "exist in a branch". Commits exist regardless of branches. Like ElpieKay said, it only needs to exist *in the repository*.

Comment: @ElpieKay @Romain Valeri Thank you guys so much! You are right: I just need to find the commit hash regardless whether it exists in the branch (i.e., even though `HEAD` points to an older commit, I can still compare two commits). Thank you! Please create an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks again!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+two+commits esp. the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10219941/7976758

Comment: For me, the one-liner that did the trick was: 
`git diff <hash of commit from 1st branch>^! <hash of commit from 2nd branch>`^!
 – the "^!" tells git not to care about commits preceding the immediate parent of the last commit taken into the comparison. I guess I did not find any compelling answer in any of the related SOs as I needed to check whether one (or more) commit(s) changed between branches (i.e. compare specific commit(s), not the rest of the branches' respective history).

Answer (score 1):

in my case, when i want to compare two different branches, i merge request one of the branch to another branch. it's not perfect but gitlab will compare those two branches, you can start from there